# Inverse Regex matching street address

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to create a regex expression. I looked at this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) post and some others but I haven't been able to solve my problem.

I'm trying to match part of a street address. I want to capture everything after the directional.

Here are some examples

5XX N Clark St

91XX S Dr Martin Luther King Jr Dr

I was able to capture everything left of the directional with this pattern.

```
\d+[X]+\s\w
```

It returns 5XX N and 91XX S

I was wondering how I can take the inverse of the regex expression. I want to return
Clark St and Dr Martin Luther King Jr Dr.

I tried doing

```
(?!\d+[X]+\s\w)
```

But it returns no matches.

Comment: Remove the found match, `re.sub(r'\d+X+\s\w', '', s)` (or `re.sub(r'^\d+X+\s\w', '', s)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following pattern :

```
import re
s1='5XX N Clark St'
s2='91XX S Dr Martin Luther King Jr Dr'
pattern="(?<=N|S|E|W).*"
k1=re.search(pattern,s1)
k2=re.search(pattern,s2)
print(k1[0])
print(k2[0])
```

Output:

```
Clark St
Dr Martin Luther King Jr Dr
```

Answer (score 1):

we do not need necessarily use regex to get the desired text from each line of the string:

```
text =["5XX N Clark St", "91XX S Dr Martin Luther King Jr Dr"]

for line in text:
    print(line.split(maxsplit=2)[-1])
```

result is:

```
Clark St
Dr Martin Luther King Jr Dr
```